# Getting the percentage of count by column SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 1 table called stats that contains every thing (project constraint) and here is the concept we have regions = a region has multiple "groupement" a groupement has multiple "Resultat_Appel" I want to get the percentage of each "groupement" in by region (by counting the "Id_Externe" which means the sum of percentage of counts = 100% , grp1 + grp2 + ... = 100% in each region Here is my Query (It's working , but when I use distinct it's not) , I need to remove duplicates "Id_Externe" from counting

WITHOUT distinct

```
   select st.Nom_Region,
   st.Groupement,
   count(st.Id_Externe)                                   as count,
   count(st.Id_Externe) * 100 / (select count(st2.Id_Externe)
                                 from stats as st2
                                 where st2.Nom_Region like st.Nom_Region
                                   and st2.Nom_Region is not null
                                   and st2.Resultat_Appel not like "=%"
                                   and st2.Groupement not like "Non Renseigné"
                                   and st2.Groupement not like "Appels post"
                                 group by st2.Nom_Region) as percent
from stats as st
where st.Nom_Region is not null
  and st.Resultat_Appel not like "=%"
  and st.Groupement not like "Non Renseigné"
  and st.Groupement not like "Appels post"

group by st.Nom_Region, st.Groupement
order by st.Nom_Region
```

USING distinct

```
    select st.Nom_Region,
   st.Groupement,
   count(distinct st.Id_Externe)                                   as count,
   count(distinct st.Id_Externe) * 100 / (select count(distinct st2.Id_Externe)
                                          from stats as st2
                                          where st2.Nom_Region like st.Nom_Region
                                            and st2.Nom_Region is not null
                                            and st2.Resultat_Appel not like "=%"
                                            and st2.Groupement not like "Non Renseigné"
                                            and st2.Groupement not like "Appels post"
                                          group by st2.Nom_Region) as percent
from stats as st
where st.Nom_Region is not null
  and st.Resultat_Appel not like "=%"
  and st.Groupement not like "Non Renseigné"
  and st.Groupement not like "Appels post"

group by st.Nom_Region, st.Groupement
order by st.Nom_Region
```

Here is an image for the result without using "distinct" on Id.Externe (OK)

[image]

and this is an image for the result using "distinct" on Id.Externe (NOT OK)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just want window functions:

```
select st.Nom_Region, st.Groupement,
       count(*) as count,
       count(*) * 100.0 / sum(count(*)) over (partition by st.Nom_Region) as percentage
from stats st
where st.Nom_Region is not null and
      st.Resultat_Appel not like '=%' and
      st.Groupement not like 'Non Renseigné' and
      st.Groupement not like 'Appels post'
group by st.Nom_Region, st.Groupement
order by st.Nom_Region;
```